# Android how custom view same with image below

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have an image. How do I create a custom view as above? It is a button.

Comment: Explain what you want, it's unclear. If button is full image, then but image in background of button

Comment: Can you explain again?. it is line and button. how can are you? same image with image button

Comment: you may simply use image button and put this image in that

Answer (score 0):

U need to create Compound View of shape Custom ImageViews.

Refer these links

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview